# How to JOIN on text between SLASHES

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Need help here.  I have one column with consistent naming.  I need to match the data between the / / in here

Brandywine Hospital / PET-CT / Renewal

which is stored in o.Name

I need to join what is between the // with the column c.Modality

**How???**    ___It is also being joined on a customer and account number

Comment: Please provide sample data in a *tabular* format and tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Your question lacks information to get any help from SO users.
Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), learn [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions.
If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and people will be very glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE` in the `ON` clause:

```
from o join
     c
     on o.name like '%/' + c.modality + '/%'
```

You could see if anything matches without the slashes:

```
     on o.name like '%' + c.modality + '%'
```

Comment: Using SQL Server 2012

Also tried using + instead of that but didn't work

Comment: @MG12345 . . . It should work with `+`, unless you have other characters in the name.

Comment: Nope.  Nothing shows.  How about this instead?

How do I get just the text between the / and / to it's own column.  

Like I want to get CT out of Hospital / CT / Trivago

Comment: You could try the above with a space after / before the slash, so '%/ ' and ' /%'